# Nest a datalist inside a tabpanel

Tags: extjs, twitter, sencha-touch, tabpanel

I am trying to nest a datalist(twitter) inside a tabpanel in sencha touch, but it doesn't load when i add this in. Not sure whats preventing it from loading.I am sure this is possible though. ANy help on this would be great

```
var timeline = viewport.textDetails = new Ext.Component({
    cls: 'timeline',

    scroll: 'vertical',
    tpl: [
        '<tpl for=".">',
        '<div class="tweet">',
        '<div class="avatar"><img src="{profile_image_url}" /></div>',
        '<div class="tweet-content">',
        '<h2>{from_user}</h2>',
        '<p>{text}</p>',
        '</div>',
        '</div>',
        '</tpl>']
});

var panel = new Ext.TabPanel({
    fullscreen: true,
    items: [timeline]
});

var reader = Ext.util.JSONP.request({
    url: 'http://search.twitter.com/search.json',
    callbackKey: 'callback',
    params: {
        q: ',test'
    },
    callback: function (data) {
        data = data.results;
        timeline.update(data);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change true to false and it works fine